# switch for dimming 2500W resistive loads (lighting)

Tags: mosfet

I need to use a switch for dimming 2500W resistive loads (lighting). Currently I am using SSRs, but looking for other options like MOSFETs. Are there such switches available?

Comment: Do you mean SCRs?  Or are you applying a PWM signal to a SSR?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why do you think MOSFETs will be better than SSRs?

Comment: SSR relay with MOSFETs exist but expensive. You. Can build your own based on two MOSFETs. Check application note TIDUC87a.pdf at TI site.

Comment: One note about designing your own alternative to off the shelf products, even assuming you come up with a working design, you would need an engineer and inspector to sign off on your system to avoid voiding your building insurance in most areas, so your cost is likely to be higher in the end even if off the shelf parts come at a premium.  In Canada for example, you need either UL(Underwriter's Labs) or CSA(Canadian Standards Association) markings on any device you install.  Even a simple solid metal cover plate bears the appropriate marking.  Anything else requires an "Exception" by inspector.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the hysteresis effects of dimming bulbs at turn on, I would use precision phase controlled pulses with a small pulse transformer that does not depend on load resistance for trigger current and thus narrow angle pulse triggers into SCR’s.  this is comparable to gate pulse triggers on 500V rated FET’s but more expensive.

It all depends on your design skill and volume.  When I did it in mid ‘70’s , I made my own pulse transformers. X 8 channels.

But keep in mind a 100W bulb if triggered on peak sine when cold, the current is 10~20x for one cycle as it decays when hot.